# Plotting learning curve in keras gives KeyError: 'val_acc'

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, pattern-recognition

I was trying to plot train and test learning curve in keras, however, the following code produces `KeyError: 'val_acc error`.

The official document `<https://keras.io/callbacks/>` states that in order to use `'val_acc'` I need to enable  validation and accuracy monitoring which I dont understand and dont know how to use in my code.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

```
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

dataframe = pandas.read_csv("iris.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:,0:4].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,4]

encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(y=Y, n_folds=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []

for i, (train, test) in enumerate(kfold):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=4, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(3, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    history=model.fit(X[train], dummy_y[train], nb_epoch=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], dummy_y[test], verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)

print( "%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores))) 


print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Looks like in Keras + Tensorflow 2.0 `val_acc` was renamed to `val_accuracy`

Comment: What is the point of doing stuff like this other than to cause everyone a lot of trouble?

Answer (score 25):

```
history_dict = history.history
print(history_dict.keys())
```

if u print keys of history_dict, you will get like this `dict_keys(['loss', 'acc', 'val_loss', 'val_acc'])`.

and edit a code like this

```
acc = history_dict['acc']
val_acc = history_dict['val_acc']
loss = history_dict['loss']
val_loss = history_dict['val_loss']
```

[Keys and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDnxj.png)

Comment: Please add a link to the official doc for reference. While this is ok, but still.

Comment: I was facing this prblm and I found this. Simple, find a type of "history_dict ". that will be a dictionary, which means the dict have keys and value.  so try to print the keys as well as value. if you print "print(history_dict.keys())" you will get dict_keys(['loss', 'acc', 'val_loss', 'val_acc']) this output. so the history object contains the dictionary. in that dictionary we have ['loss', 'acc', 'val_loss', 'val_acc'] keys. for these keys we have values. so we can plot a graph using keys (in dict we can use values only via keys).

Answer (score 12):

The main point everyone misses to mention is that this **Key Error** is related to the naming of metrics during `model.compile(...)`. You need to be consistent with the way you name your accuracy metric inside `model.compile(....,metrics=['<metric name>'])`. Your history callback object will receive the dictionary containing key-value pairs as defined in metrics.

So, if your metric is `metrics=['acc']`, you can access them in history object with `history.history['acc']` but if you define metric as `metrics=['accuracy']`, you need to change to `history.history['accuracy']` to access the value, in order to avoid **Key Error**. I hope it helps.

N.B. Here's a [link to the metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/) you can use in Keras.

Comment: Excellent answer. In my case I had multiple `keras.metrics.Precision()` classes and could not figure out why I was getting `val_precision_1`, `val_precision_2`, and such... this comment solves it. I have to give the same name to every class `keras.metrics.Percision(name='precision')` to count on that key being there in the history object.

Answer (score 11):

You may need to enable the validation split of your trainset. Usually, the validation happens in 1/3 of the trainset. In your code, make the change as  given below:

```
history=model.fit(X[train], dummy_y[train],validation_split=0.33,nb_epoch=200, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
```

It works!

Answer (score 6):

If you upgrade keras older version (e.g. 2.2.5) to 2.3.0 (or newer) which is compatible with Tensorflow 2.0, you might have such error (*e.g. KeyError: 'acc'*). Both **acc** and **val_acc** has been renamed to **accuracy** and **val_accuracy** respectively. Renaming them in script will solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

to get any val_* data (`val_acc`, `val_loss`, ...), you need to first set the validation.

first method (will validate from what you give it):

```
model.fit(validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

second method (will validate from a part of the training data):

```
model.fit(validation_split=0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed acc to accuracy and my problem solved. Tensorflow 2+

e.g.

```
accuracy = history_dict['accuracy']
val_accuracy = history_dict['val_acccuracy']
```

Answer (score 0):

This error also happens when you specify the `validation_data=(X_test, Y_test)` and your `X_test` and/or `Y_test` are empty. To check this, print the shape of `X_test` and `Y_test` respectively. In this case, the `model.fit(validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), ...)` method ran but because the validation set was empty, it didn't create a dictionary key for `val_loss` in the `history.history` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing `objective='val_accuracy'`to `objective=["val_accuracy"]` in

```
tuner = kt.BayesianOptimization(model_builder,
                         objective=["val_accuracy"],
                         max_trials=80,
                         seed=123) 
tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
```

I have TensorFlow 2+.

Answer (score 0):

rename as follows :)

```
plt.plot(history.history["accuracy"])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
```